# Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/hibernatedb]

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm trying to make a software using a database, and after many tries i have followed a [tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFMOZY4z6bE&index=3&list=PL_5aB2ncz1K8swf-bMC6cQpfzF12VxpHt#t=595.874648).

I'm using java 8, PostgreSQL 9.4 and Hibernate 5.2.2 (plus JBoss Tools 4.4.1).

I followed the tutorial until running the application, but then the following error message appears, saying that the application can't connect to the database :

```
oct. 15, 2016 2:53:35 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.2.Final}
oct. 15, 2016 2:53:35 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
oct. 15, 2016 2:53:35 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
oct. 15, 2016 2:53:35 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
oct. 15, 2016 2:53:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
oct. 15, 2016 2:53:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/hibernatedb]
oct. 15, 2016 2:53:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=postgresql, password=****}
oct. 15, 2016 2:53:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
oct. 15, 2016 2:53:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at com.kg.hibernate.main.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:16)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/hibernatedb]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
    ... 14 more
```

HibernateTest.java

```
package com.kg.hibernate.main;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.kg.hibernate.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        UserDetails user= new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("Kévin");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session= sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }
}
```

UserDetails.java

```
package com.kg.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC

        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database Connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">kgware</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgresql</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="com.kg.hibernate.UserDetails"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

I searched over many forums a solution but couldn't find any...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: In your connection url value, try to change "jdbc:postgres" by "jdbc:postgresql". I hope this help you.

Comment: Ouah such a little mistake... Thx very much ! Sometimes you need someone else to find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Connection String is wrong modifty from

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
```

to

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
```

Comment: Strange ... EclipseLink worked with "postgres", now switched to Hibernate and now it needs "postgresql" .. anyway... now it works.